# What version control tool can generate this header

Tags: version-control, comments, ssms, code-generation

This is from a sql script. What tool can generate this? Thanks

```
--USE [MY_TABLE]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[adminIncExp]    Script Date: 03/05/2010 09:14:12 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:                  <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description:  <Description,,>
-- =============================================
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server management studio. This is part of one of the standard templates (looks like the Create Procedure template) - it has nothing to do with source control.

See the [How to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179334.aspx) article on templates in SSMS on MSDN.